# How to handle multipart/form-data on client side?

Tags: javascript, rest, multipartform-data, axios, web-frontend

I am building a frontend application in which I'm going to retrieve files via the API provided from backend.
The API consumes json request like most restful APIs whereas responses file in **`multipart/form-data`** type. Therefore when I tried to get the body of the response with [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios), data appears like this.

> --77d4f4ac-bcb2-4457-ad81-810cf8c3ce47
>      Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=20170822.txt
>      Content-Type: text/plain
>
> ```
> ...data...
> ```
>
> --77d4f4ac-bcb2-4457-ad81-810cf8c3ce47--

It confused me quite a lot since I'm used to deal with raw data with [blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) object. However it seems that I have to parse the response by myself here in order to get the raw data. I searched around but found almost all of the articles and questions are discussing about server-side handling. So my question can be separated into 2 pieces.

1. Is it okay/possible to handle `multipart/form-data` on client side?
2. If it is, how can I handle it? (Of course, it will be really appreciated if there's a library for it)

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do exactly but there is this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: @Will Hi, Will. Thanks for your comment. My question, in one sentence, is how to retrieve a binary file in multipart/form-data content type. Does it make sense?

Comment: Pretty sure you have to parse it yourself. Here's a Gist that has a solution: https://gist.github.com/dcollien/76d17f69afe748afad7ff3a15ff9a08a

Comment: @Will wow, it seems that this gist will save a lot of time for me ;)